# Chip antenna, what to do with power and bottom planes

Tags: antenna, routing, pcb-layers

I'm designing a board which uses a chip antenna.
According to the datasheet, there should be no copper on all layers under the
antenna. There's also should be some ground plane on the top layer with a know distance between the plane and the chip.

My question is : what about power and bottom layers ? Should I add a ground band
around the clear area or should I just do nothing ?

Datasheet : http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/276/0479480001_ANTENNAS-701294.pdf
(link to app notes and other relateds in the top of the datasheet)

Comment: You should do whatever your design tool requires to produce a board with no copper on any layer under the antenna.

Comment: A "keepout" zone for each layer is a good idea if your EDA software supports it.

Comment: @ThePhoton and rdsc : Yes sure, but should I add some ground around the keepout on power and bottom layer ?

Answer (score 1):

You should maintain the prescribed keepout zone on all layers<sup>1</sup>.  You will need a ground copper pour for the matching network on the top layer near the antenna.  It should be "stitched" with vias to the inner layer ground plane.

My gut feeling tells me that it's not a bad idea to have ground on every layer around the keepout zone.  I would make a via "fence" around the keepout zone.

<sup>1</sup> <sub>What ThePhoton said in his [comment](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/210048/chip-antenna-what-to-do-with-power-and-bottom-planes#comment444942_210048).</sub>

<sup>2</sup> <sub>[Molex app note](http://www.molex.com/pdm_docs/as/AS-47948-001.pdf) for this antenna.</sub>

<sup>3</sup> <sub>I'm not an RF and antenna expert.  An actual RF speciallist can do this question better justice. I'm writing this answer only as a fallback.</sub>